# Visual Studio code gets autoremoved after upgrading system

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, upgrade, visual-studio-code

I manually installed visual studio code in ubuntu.
As soon as i run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

the system gets properly updated.
After, I run the command

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

which autoremoves the installed vs code.

How to prevent vs code to get autoremoved after upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you typed `sudo apt upgrade` and not `sudo apt full-upgade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

If vs code is a .deb package, `upgrade` would never uninstall it, while `full-upgrade` or `dist-upgrade` might.

If vs code isn't a package, then either might break a vs code install due to incompatibilities with upgraded packages (which is one of the downsides of using unpackaged software) - but it won't trigger an uninstall (because as far as apt is concerned, there wouldn't be anything to uninstall).

`upgrade` will upgrade packages (and install any new dependencies) as long as they don't require any other package to be removed.  `full-upgrade` (aka `dist-upgrade`) will upgrade packages even if that requires conflicting packages to be removed.

See `man apt` and `man apt-get` for details.  Here's a relevant short extract from `apt`'s man page, with some highlighting and reformatting:

> `upgrade` (`apt-get(8)`)
>
> `upgrade` is used to install available upgrades of all packages
> currently installed on the system from the sources configured via
> `sources.list(5)`. New packages will be installed if required to
> satisfy dependencies, **but existing packages will never be removed**.
> If an upgrade for a package requires the removal of an installed
> package the upgrade for this package isn't performed.
>
> `full-upgrade` (`apt-get(8)`)
>
> `full-upgrade` performs the function of `upgrade` but will remove
> currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the
> system as a whole.

---

If you want/need to do a dist-upgrade then you will need to upgrade vs code too, to a version that doesn't conflict with your other packages.  This may require waiting for Microsoft to release a new version of the package....or that may have already been released and all you need to do is download and install it.  Impossible to tell for sure because you haven't provided any details about package names or versions.

If you know the name of the vs code package and have `aptitude` installed you can run `aptitude why-not packagename` to get a hint about what other package(s) might be triggering an uninstall.